# ¿Como instalar Django en un virtual environment?

Tags: python, django

estoy teniendo problemas con unas instalaciones de Django que hice en un virtual environment y basicamente tengo una sola duda:

Es necesario instalar Django dentro de cada nuevo virtual environment que creo? es decir, si creo un nuevo proyecto de Django en un virtual environment, tengo que volverlo a instalar siempre?

LO que sucede es que hace un tiempo hice un virtualenv e instalé Django en él. Luego lo eliminé y ahora creé otro y volví a instalar el framework dentro pero obtengo este error y no se como repararlo:

[image: Error :(]

No me permite ejecutar django-admin.py, solo cuando antepongo la palabra Python, pero aun asi no me permite ejecutar nuevos proyectos.... no se que hacer! :(

Gracias a todos.

Answer (score 0):

En efecto, cada *virtualenv* es un entorno aislado en el cual debes instalar los paquetes necesarios para hacer funcionar tu proyecto. Te recomiendo generar un archivo con los requerimientos (si no lo tienes) y ejecutarlo, con eso debería solventarse tu problema.

... y no olvides que cada *virtualenv* es un entorno separado donde puedes llevar proyectos diferentes.

Answer (score 0):

te recomiendo usar Linux en vez de windows para trabajar con Django y las virtualenvs, ya que con es mas fácil actualizar a nuevas versiones de ambas con simples comandos, mientras que con Windows la cosa se complica al tener que descargar instaladores para todo. Al parecer tu problema se da porque no tenes activado tu entorno virtual, entonces no puede encontrar las herramientas de Django instaladas para poder usarlas.

En linux podés hacer lo siguiente.

Instalás Virtualenv, y una vez hecho eso:

1. Activás tu virtualenv con  `source tuVirtualenv/bin/activate`.
2. Instalás Django con `pip install django`
3. Creas tu proyecto con `django-admin.py startproject tuProyecto`
4. Entras a la carpeta del proyecto y ya podés trabajar con Django tranquilamente.

Para desactivar la virtualenv para cambiar a otra o por cualquier otro motivo lo podés hacer corriendo el comando `deactivate`. Cada vez que quieras trabajar con tu proyecto no olvides activar tu virtualenv con `source tuVirtualenv/bin/activate`.

Espero haberte ayudado. Saludos